# Case Sensitive create duplicate in dataframe inspite of Distinct in Spark Scala

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark with scala 2.4.

```
spark.sqlContext.sql("set spark.sql.caseSensitive=false")
    spark.sql("select Distinct p.Area,c.Remarks from mytable c join areatable p on c.id=p.id where c.remarks = 'Sufficient Amounts'")
```

**i have used Distinct even than i am getting 3 records for each Individual Record.**

```
DISTRICT_1| Sufficient Amounts
District_1| Sufficient Amounts
district_1| Sufficient Amounts
DISTRICT_10|Sufficient Amounts
District_10|Sufficient Amounts
district_10|Sufficient Amounts
```

Even i set explicitely `spark.sqlContext.sql("set spark.sql.caseSensitive=false").`

**Expected output:**

```
DISTRICT_1  |Sufficient Amounts
DISTRICT_10 |Sufficient Amounts
```

Do i need to set something. Please share your Thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`spark.sql.caseSensitive`](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/22184) is used to for **case insensitive** column names (not to convert column values) instead

- Use **`window row_number`()** function for this case.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()

//+-----------+------------------+
//|       Area|           Remarks|
//+-----------+------------------+
//| DISTRICT_1|Sufficient Amounts|
//| District_1|Sufficient Amounts|
//| district_1|Sufficient Amounts|
//|DISTRICT_10|Sufficient Amounts|
//|District_10|Sufficient Amounts|
//|district_10|Sufficient Amounts|
//+-----------+------------------+

df.createOrReplaceTempView("mytable")

import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

spark.sql("SET spark.sql.parser.quotedRegexColumnNames=true")

sql("select `(rn)?+.+` from (select *, row_number() over(partition by lower(Area) order by 1) as rn from mytable)q where q.rn =1").show()

//+-----------+------------------+
//|       Area|           Remarks|
//+-----------+------------------+
//| DISTRICT_1|Sufficient Amounts|
//|DISTRICT_10|Sufficient Amounts|
//+-----------+------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a ton......... if the same output i want to visualize , do spark scala have library like plotly in pyspark........ Please guide me.

Comment: @Aryan, I haven't personally used plotly libraray in pyspark yet, but its doable here is the link guiding all steps for setup plotly https://plotly.com/python/v3/apache-spark/

Comment: Thank you Sir..... but what i am looking is some visualization tool for Scala Spark just similar to plotly which is supported in python.... i tried zeppelin for first time, very difficult to configure.

Comment: @Aryan, I think **zeppelin** is way to go for UI(visualization) for spark, as zeppelin supports `scala,python,shell..etc` other interpreters too and we can get alot of community support! Please open as new question to get more visibility to check what are other tools we can use for spark UI visualization interpreters.